# How to set udp buffer size for a docker container?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel

I would like to set the UDP buffer size for a docker container. Though, the UDP buffer size is a setting related to the kernel and it corresponds to that of the host, I see that, I don't see my host setting of the buffer size affecting my container.

Here is what I have tried:

**On host**

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_default = 4194304
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max = 4194304
```

and to verify (**on host**)

```
sysctl net.core.rmem_default
net.core.rmem_default = 4194304

sysctl net.core.rmem_max
net.core.rmem_max = 4194304
```

But, when I run in the container (say alpine).

```
docker run -it alpine
```

**and in alpine ash**

```
sysctl net.core.rmem_default
sysctl: error: 'net.core.rmem_default' is an unknown key
```

The same is the case with `rmem_max` also.

However, to my surprise, I see

```
sysctl net.core.rmem_default
net.core.somaxconn = 128
```

I am able to set the above on docker container using `--sysctl` argument.

```
docker run -it --sysctl net.core.somaxconn=125 alpine
/ # sysctl net.core.somaxconn
net.core.somaxconn = 125
```

But, what I need is `rmem_default` and `rmem_max` sizes.

If this option is not provided through `--sysctl` flag and that the setting depends on the host machine, then

**How can I prove that the buffer size on the container is same as that of the host?**

Moreover, during many tests, I came to know that the packets are being dropped (I think, it is because of some low buffer size being set).

I also tried writing to the `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default` in the container but I got **cannot stat error**. I did not understand why there is no such file as `rmem_default` and the like (`rmem_max` etc) which are found on the host in the docker `/proc`.

I have heard that the host `/proc` is mounted on the container. Is it true? It doesn't seem to be considering the above scenario.

Also, editing the `sysctl.conf` and calling `sysctl -p` also did not help.

Feel free to move this question to unix.stackexchange.com if it makes sense there.

Comment: You can still start container in the host network `--net=host`, where you will be able to check `sysctl net.core.rmem_default`.

Comment: @JanGaraj I have tried it, the problem is it is to be run on a Kubernetes cluster, so for all nodes, I need to set the same buffer size, because I don't know on which node the container will be started. Moreover, if different applications with different udp buffer sizes run on the Kubernetes cluster, then it will become difficult for me which is why I am looking to specify that at the container level.

Comment: You can use nodeselector in k8s. It looks like this config is not a namespaced config, so you can't configure it on the container level.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that those values are not namespaced, that means they are shared between all network namespaces. There is a kernel patch in state RFC since 2017 which wants to make them namespaced:
[[RFC] net: make net.core.{r,w}mem_{default,max} namespaced](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netdev/patch/20170726170333.24580-1-mcroce@redhat.com/)

This patch alone would not allow you to use them within a kubernetes pod.
You would need to allow the sysctls like described in [Using sysctls in a Kubernetes Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/)